# Firebase SDK Facebook login wont work if email is already registered

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm wondering if it is possible to link a previously user created with email & password with Facebook login if the email is the same?

I've tested registering and logging in with Facebook and it works fine, same for email & password, but if I already have my facebook email registered then the Facebook log in button won't work and the accounts are not linked at all.

I don't think the code is necessary but either way I'm puting it below:

```
$(document).on('click', "#btn-login-fb", function (event) {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('public_profile');
    provider.addScope('email');
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
        .then(function () {
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
        });
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
            var SendData = {
            uidAux: user.uid,
            FotoPerfilAux: user.photoURL,
            NomeCompleto: user.displayName,
            Email: user.email,
            FotoPerfilAux: user.photoURL,
            Telefone: user.phoneNumber
            };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CadastraUsuarioFacebook", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(SendData),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).always(function (data, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
            }
        });
        }
        window.location.href = '/Portal/PortalCliente';
    }).catch(function (error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        var email = error.email;
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: You can certainly write code to link an existing Firebase Auth account with Facebook.  I don't see that you're trying that with what you show here.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, definetly going to try out the solution you pointed out but for Google login it was pretty easy firebase would link it automatically if the email was verified so I thought that for Facebook it would work the same way

Comment: There is nothing automatic for linking.  You have to write the code to make sure that the user actually has the credentials for the other account.  A matching email address is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to [link a Firebase Auth account with an authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) such as Facebook, it's required to write code to link the other account with the Firebase account.  It doesn't happen automatically.